# Problems with bar plot and tidyr when data are missing

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr

I am trying to plot a simple bar graph with counts of certain events by year. Here's the data:

```
> DPUT(all.events)
structure(list(YEAR = c("1987", "1988", "1989", "1990", "1991", 
"1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1998", "2000", "2001", 
"2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", 
"2010", "2011", "2013", "2015", "2016"), count = c(3L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L)), .Names = c("YEAR", "count"), row.names = c(NA, 
-26L), class = "data.frame")
```

and here's my `ggplot` script:

```
ggplot(tidyr::complete(all.events,YEAR,fill=list(count=0)),
       aes(x=YEAR,y=count)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
scale_y_continuous(limit=c(0,15),expand=c(0, 0)) +
scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(1985,1990,1995,2000,2005,2010,2015),
                 labels=c(1985,1990,1995,2000,2005,2010,2015)) +
theme_bw(base_size = 13) +
xlab("") + ylab("No of events")
```

What I hoped that the `complete` would do, and what it has done on prior occasions, is to insert years along the x-axis also where the count=0. The plot I get is the one below, where there are years missing corresponding to where the count=0:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: change your `YEAR` to numeric : `all.events$YEAR <- as.numeric(all.events$YEAR)`. At the moment it's a character, and so `ggplot` is treating it as categorical, not continuous / numeric

Comment: Yes, once `YEAR` is numeric you can use `full_seq` to add all the missing years: `complete(all.events, YEAR = full_seq(YEAR, 1), fill = list(count = 0) )`

Comment: As a rule of thumb, I'm trying to use a  `date` or `datetime` scale (which essentially is a numeric scale) when aggregating by week, month, or year. Instead of `as.integer(YEAR)`, you can do `lubridate::ymd(YEAR, truncated = 2L)`. The benefit becomes more visible in [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47619794/3817004)

Answer (score 1):

`complete` will not create values out of nothing. From the help at `?complete`:

> For continuous variables, you may need to fill in values that don't appear in the data: to do so use expressions like `year = 2010:2020` or `year = full_seq(year)`

So, as stated in the comments you should first convert `YEAR` to a numeric, but they key point is to specify that you want the full sequence (or manually `YEAR  = 1987:2016`).

```
tidyr::complete(all.events, full_seq(YEAR), fill = list(count=0))
```